# Backend not working on MERN app on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios

I have deployed my mern app on heroku. My front end is being displayed, but I can't access my database, probably my server is causing issue.
My server code

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
// Database Connection
const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://Toor_300:ARh3SwhrBl5Nvaur@cluster0.rudek.mongodb.net/courses_site"
mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser:true })
    .then(() => app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening to Port')))
    .catch((err) => console.log(`Connection Error: ${error}`))

// Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cors())

// Heroku
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client','build')))
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build'))
    })
}

// Routes
app.use("/register", userRoute)
app.use("/admin", adminRoute)
```

My Axios Api in React

```
import axios from 'axios'

const CONNECTION_URL = "http://localhost:5000/admin"

export const createUser = (user) => axios.post(CONNECTION_URL, user)

export const getUser = (user) => axios.get(`${CONNECTION_URL}/login/${user.email}&${user.password}`)

export const resetPassword = (email) => axios.get(`${CONNECTION_URL}/reset/${email}`)

export const updatePassword = (info) => axios.patch(`${CONNECTION_URL}/reset`, info)
```

I have tried many options but it didn't seem to work. I think the error is with my axios. The url provided is local how do I make it dynamic?

Comment: Hope the below blog helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

https://coursework.vschool.io/deploying-mern-app-to-heroku/

I'm always following this blog to deploy the MERN app you have to mainly focus on directory structure and package.json setup on the server side